# Weird iOS crash with very little information, is it a network issue / iOS issue?

Tags: ios, cordova, ios8, crash, newrelic

Team,

I am facing a crash in my iOS application which is actually built using cordova/phonegap framework. There are very little native components and few phone gap plugins are used. Got the crash report from one of the crash reporting third party framework - newrelic.

Below is the reason for the maximum number of crashes. There are several threads, which contains almost no information regarding my own build name and thats the reason didn't include complete crash report.

```
Thread 13 Crashed:
0   libsystem_network.dylib       0x37814998  _tcp_connection_id + 22936
1   libsystem_network.dylib       0x37826317  _tcp_connection_host_resolve_result + 94999
2   libsystem_dnssd.dylib         0x377a2aa1  _handle_addrinfo_response + 10913
3   libsystem_dnssd.dylib         0x377a15dd  _DNSServiceProcessResult + 5597
4   libdispatch.dylib             0x376e9709  __dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 96009
5   libdispatch.dylib             0x376e2f3d  __dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 69437
6   libdispatch.dylib             0x376de419  __dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 50201
7   libdispatch.dylib             0x376de0a9  __dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 49321
8   libdispatch.dylib             0x376e00d3  __dispatch_root_queue_drain + 57555
9   libdispatch.dylib             0x376e11fb  __dispatch_worker_thread3 + 61947
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x37851e25  __pthread_wqthread + 3621
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x37851b78  _start_wqthread + 2936
```

Any suggestions would be of great use.

**Additional Info - One of the sample crash report of similar kind of crashes:**

```
Hardware Model:      iPod Touch 5 (iPod5,1)
Process:         <App Name> [201]
Path:            <App Path>
Identifier:      <App ID>
Code Type:       arm-unknown
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2015-05-05 01:13:14 +0000
Launch Time:     2015-05-05 01:13:14 +0000
OS Version:      iOS 8.1.2 (12B440)

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Crashed Thread:  14

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'SIGSEGV', reason: ''

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x31448518  _mach_msg_trap + 5400
1   CoreFoundation                0x2368659b  ___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 845211
2   CoreFoundation                0x23684b61  ___CFRunLoopRun + 838497
3   CoreFoundation                0x235d1b31  _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 105265
4   CoreFoundation                0x235d1943  _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104771
5   GraphicsServices              0x2a98a051  _GSEventRunModal + 36945
6   UIKit                         0x26bc76f1  _UIApplicationMain + 452337
7   <App Build Name>                   0x11cfbf    main (main.m:32)
8   <App Build Name>                   0x117ce8    [CDVTimer .cxx_destruct] + 134376

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x314482c8  _kevent64 + 4808
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x3136ab7b  __dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 72571

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x31448518  _mach_msg_trap + 5400
1   CoreFoundation                0x2368659b  ___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 845211
2   CoreFoundation                0x23684b61  ___CFRunLoopRun + 838497
3   CoreFoundation                0x235d1b31  _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 105265
4   CoreFoundation                0x235d1943  _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104771
5   CFNetwork                     0x2318678f  [NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 509839
6   Foundation                    0x243d399b  ___NSThread__main__ + 854427
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314dae67  __pthread_body + 11879
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314daddb  __pthread_start + 11739
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b84  _thread_start + 2948

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x31448518  _mach_msg_trap + 5400
1   CoreFoundation                0x2368659b  ___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 845211
2   CoreFoundation                0x23684b61  ___CFRunLoopRun + 838497
3   CoreFoundation                0x235d1b31  _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 105265
4   CoreFoundation                0x235d1943  _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104771
5   WebCore                       0x2e9b7c81  __ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 535681
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314dae67  __pthread_body + 11879
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314daddb  __pthread_start + 11739
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b84  _thread_start + 2948

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3145bb38  ___psynch_cvwait + 84792
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314db2b1  _pthread_cond_wait + 12977
2   libc++.1.dylib                0x305c1fa9  __ZNSt3__118condition_variable4waitERNS_11unique_lockINS_5mutexEEE + 24489
3   JavaScriptCore                0x24894f9b  __ZN3JSC14BlockAllocator22blockFreeingThreadMainEv + 85915
4   JavaScriptCore                0x2489144f  __ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 70735
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314dae67  __pthread_body + 11879
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314daddb  __pthread_start + 11739
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b84  _thread_start + 2948

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3145bb38  ___psynch_cvwait + 84792
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314db2b1  _pthread_cond_wait + 12977
2   libc++.1.dylib                0x305c1fa9  __ZNSt3__118condition_variable4waitERNS_11unique_lockINS_5mutexEEE + 24489
3   JavaScriptCore                0x24a59b65  __ZN3JSC8GCThread16waitForNextPhaseEv + 1940325
4   JavaScriptCore                0x24a59bc9  __ZN3JSC8GCThread12gcThreadMainEv + 1940425
5   JavaScriptCore                0x2489144f  __ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 70735
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314dae67  __pthread_body + 11879
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314daddb  __pthread_start + 11739
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b84  _thread_start + 2948

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x31448518  _mach_msg_trap + 5400
1   CoreFoundation                0x2368659b  ___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 845211
2   CoreFoundation                0x23684b61  ___CFRunLoopRun + 838497
3   CoreFoundation                0x235d1b31  _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 105265
4   CoreFoundation                0x235d1943  _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104771
5   WebCore                       0x2e9e0f8d  __ZN7WebCoreL15runLoaderThreadEPv + 704397
6   JavaScriptCore                0x2489144f  __ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 70735
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314dae67  __pthread_body + 11879
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314daddb  __pthread_start + 11739
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b84  _thread_start + 2948

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3145bb38  ___psynch_cvwait + 84792
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314db2b1  _pthread_cond_wait + 12977
2   JavaScriptCore                0x248950df  __ZN3WTF15ThreadCondition9timedWaitERNS_5MutexEd + 86239
3   WebCore                       0x2f25324b  __ZN3WTF12MessageQueueINS_8FunctionIFvvEEEE33waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeoutIZNS4_14waitForMessageEvEUlRKS3_E_EENSt3__110unique_ptrIS3_NS9_14default_deleteIS3_EEEERNS_22MessageQueueWaitResultEOT_d + 9560651
4   WebCore                       0x2ea76707  __ZN7WebCore13StorageThread16threadEntryPointEv + 1316615
5   JavaScriptCore                0x2489144f  __ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 70735
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314dae67  __pthread_body + 11879
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314daddb  __pthread_start + 11739
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b84  _thread_start + 2948

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3145bb38  ___psynch_cvwait + 84792
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314db2b1  _pthread_cond_wait + 12977
2   JavaScriptCore                0x248950df  __ZN3WTF15ThreadCondition9timedWaitERNS_5MutexEd + 86239
3   WebCore                       0x2ebd2d81  __ZN3WTF12MessageQueueIN7WebCore12DatabaseTaskEE33waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeoutIZNS3_14waitForMessageEvEUlRKS2_E_EENSt3__110unique_ptrIS2_NS8_14default_deleteIS2_EEEERNS_22MessageQueueWaitResultEOT_d + 2743681
4   WebCore                       0x2ebd2109  __ZN7WebCore14DatabaseThread14databaseThreadEv + 2740489
5   JavaScriptCore                0x2489144f  __ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 70735
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314dae67  __pthread_body + 11879
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314daddb  __pthread_start + 11739
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b84  _thread_start + 2948

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3145c08c  _select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 86156
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314dae67  __pthread_body + 11879
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314daddb  __pthread_start + 11739
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b84  _thread_start + 2948

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x31448518  _mach_msg_trap + 5400
1   CoreFoundation                0x2368659b  ___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 845211
2   CoreFoundation                0x23684b61  ___CFRunLoopRun + 838497
3   CoreFoundation                0x235d1b31  _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 105265
4   CoreFoundation                0x2361b4fb  _CFRunLoopRun + 406779
5   CoreMotion                    0x23ed8d23  _CLSF_thorntonUpdate_6x6 + 261411
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314dae67  __pthread_body + 11879
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314daddb  __pthread_start + 11739
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b84  _thread_start + 2948

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b70  _start_wqthread + 2928

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b70  _start_wqthread + 2928

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3145c0c4  _select$DARWIN_EXTSN$NOCANCEL + 86212
1   libsystem_dnssd.dylib         0x31429933  _DNSServiceGetAddrInfo + 10547
2   libsystem_network.dylib       0x314acb37  _tcp_connection_host_start + 92983
3   libsystem_network.dylib       0x31499fad  _tcp_connection_start_host + 16301
4   libsystem_network.dylib       0x314a1437  _tcp_connection_start_direct_connect + 46135
5   libsystem_network.dylib       0x3149a4eb  _tcp_connection_handle_proxy_complete + 17643
6   libsystem_network.dylib       0x314addcd  _network_proxy_complete + 97741
7   libsystem_network.dylib       0x314ad2ff  _tcp_connection_host_resolve_result + 94975
8   libsystem_dnssd.dylib         0x31429aa1  _handle_addrinfo_response + 10913
9   libsystem_dnssd.dylib         0x314285dd  _DNSServiceProcessResult + 5597
10  libdispatch.dylib             0x31370709  __dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 96009
11  libdispatch.dylib             0x31369f3d  __dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 69437
12  libdispatch.dylib             0x31365419  __dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 50201
13  libdispatch.dylib             0x313650a9  __dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 49321
14  libdispatch.dylib             0x313670d3  __dispatch_root_queue_drain + 57555
15  libdispatch.dylib             0x313681fb  __dispatch_worker_thread3 + 61947
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8e25  __pthread_wqthread + 3621
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b78  _start_wqthread + 2936

Thread 14 Crashed:
0   libsystem_network.dylib       0x3149b998  _tcp_connection_id + 22936
1   libsystem_network.dylib       0x314ad317  _tcp_connection_host_resolve_result + 94999
2   libsystem_dnssd.dylib         0x31429aa1  _handle_addrinfo_response + 10913
3   libsystem_dnssd.dylib         0x314285dd  _DNSServiceProcessResult + 5597
4   libdispatch.dylib             0x31370709  __dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 96009
5   libdispatch.dylib             0x31369f3d  __dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 69437
6   libdispatch.dylib             0x31365419  __dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 50201
7   libdispatch.dylib             0x313650a9  __dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 49321
8   libdispatch.dylib             0x313670d3  __dispatch_root_queue_drain + 57555
9   libdispatch.dylib             0x313681fb  __dispatch_worker_thread3 + 61947
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8e25  __pthread_wqthread + 3621
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b78  _start_wqthread + 2936

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x31448568  _semaphore_wait_trap + 5480
1   CFNetwork                     0x2316bd6f  _CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 400751
2   CFNetwork                     0x23186caf  [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 511151
3   <App Build Name>                   0x4047e3    [NRMANSURLConnectionSupport poseImplementationBlockForSelector:]_block_invoke] (NRMANSURLConnectionSupport.m:202)
4   <App Build Name>                   0x4111a7    [NRMAHarvesterConnection send:] (NRMAHarvesterConnection.m:97)
5   <App Build Name>                   0x411a03    [NRMAHarvesterConnection sendData:] (NRMAHarvesterConnection.m:160)
6   <App Build Name>                   0x400435    [NRMAHarvester connected] (NRMAHarvester.m:272)
7   <App Build Name>                   0x401eeb    [NRMAHarvester execute] (NRMAHarvester.m:509)
8   <App Build Name>                   0x400bf9    [NRMAHarvester disconnected] (NRMAHarvester.m:354)
9   <App Build Name>                   0x401ea7    [NRMAHarvester execute] (NRMAHarvester.m:504)
10  <App Build Name>                   0x405ea1    [NRMAHarvestController start]_block_invoke_2] (NRMAHarvestController.m:143)
11  libdispatch.dylib             0x3135b423  __dispatch_call_block_and_release + 9251
12  libdispatch.dylib             0x313655d9  __dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 50649
13  libdispatch.dylib             0x313650a9  __dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 49321
14  libdispatch.dylib             0x313670d3  __dispatch_root_queue_drain + 57555
15  libdispatch.dylib             0x313681fb  __dispatch_worker_thread3 + 61947
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8e25  __pthread_wqthread + 3621
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b78  _start_wqthread + 2936

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3145c9cc  ___workq_kernreturn + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b78  _start_wqthread + 2936

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3145c9cc  ___workq_kernreturn + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x314d8b78  _start_wqthread + 2936

Thread 14 crashed with arm-unknown Thread state:
    lr: 0x314ad361              sp: 0x3da9880               pc: 0x3149b998              cpsr: 0x60000030        
    r0: 0                       r1: 0xfffeffee              r2: 0x1000                  r3: 0xfff               
    r4: 0x3da9880               r5: 0x15e00e90              r6: 0xfffeffee              r7: 0x3da98f8           
    r8: 0                       r9: 0x15ee5000              r10: 0xfffeffee             r11: 0x15e00e90         
    r12: 0x33b631ec
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happen to too many users want access at same time . Please make sure making sure the getaddrinfo[Thread 13 (2)] isn't called too often by too many threads at the same time. Also added a local cache(dns) for the results.

Comment: I have not used getaddrinfo in my application. Do you think this will be internally called by iOS through some private frameworks? I didn't find any proper stack track of calling this. What do you think?

Comment: Yes , its called internally otherwise this crash never come

Comment: Any idea to avoid this?

Comment: Need to review your app before commenting any further

Answer (score 0):

Do not use getaddrinfo to get a device's primary (in other words, networked) interface using a host's own hostname.  That is no longer supported on Macintoshes or iOS devices; and in most cases, will take 30 seconds to complete.

From manpage for Mac OS 10.12.x:

Historically, passing a host's own hostname to getaddrinfo() has been a popular technique for determining that host's IP address(es), but this is fragile, and doesn't work reliably in all cases. The appropriate way for software to discover the IP address(es) of the host it is running on is to use getifaddrs(3).